# Functionality code in event handler bad practice?

Tags: c#

I was reading some C# coding standards and it has this:

"The event handler should not contain the code to perform the required action. Rather call another method from the event handler"

I was wondering if there is a reason for this (performance or something else) or if it is just a style preference?

Comment: Do you have a reference for this coding standard? The context may help here.

Comment: It's 13. from section 9 from here: http://www.dotnetspider.com/tutorials/BestPractices.aspx. I am currently writing my project's standards and looking at various coding standards for inspiration and I couldn't work out if this was just a recommendation or had some solid performance issue, for example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An event handler is meant to connect the GUI to your business logic.

If you have a textbox to enter a user's name and an Add button, clicking the Add button should merely call `_userRepository.AddUser(UsernameTextbox.Text)`. You don't want business logic in event handlers.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but I am curious as to whether there is a solid performance or other issue or merely a matter of good style?

Comment: A matter of good style, to be precise it's floating somewhere between [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), [Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) and [Cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)). You don't want the code that's required to add a user to the database (given the example) to reside somewhere else than in fact in the UserRepository class. You [abstract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science)) this to a simple AddUser call.

Comment: This is not a matter of performance or style.  In the case of UI applications specifically, UI event handlers should never have business logic as this leads to bad coupling (e.g. if you later wanted to reuse the logic outside of a UI context such as a raw class library, you would have to extract it or duplicate it).

Comment: That's all good answers and pretty much what I suspected but I wanted to make sure in case the powers that be argue why it is a recommendation in the coding standards. I also had a moment of doubting myself. Thanks muchly!

Comment: Expressiveness is another concern.  Event handler methods are typically named after the event that triggers them, not after what they are trying to accomplish.  Even if you are only adding GUI-concerned code, adding the code in the form of an intention revealingly named method can help the next person considerably.