# How can I make a coderefactoring at the code below?

Tags: c#, printing

Does anyone has tips for me? 
I am new at coding :-)

```
private void PrintFile_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        PrintDocument printDoc2 = new PrintDocument();
        List<PrintDocument> docList = new List<PrintDocument>();
        printDoc.DocumentName = @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\1\1.pdf";
        printDoc2.DocumentName = @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\1\2.pdf";
        docList.Add(printDoc);
        docList.Add(printDoc2);
        printDoc.Print();
        printDoc2.Print();
    }
```

Comment: you want to print the same document multiple times? Just use a for loop

Comment: No i just want to print some documents. I found this and it works. Can you help me by coderefactoring?

Comment: Why do you create a list? It is not used after adding those elements, so its a waste of lines, memory and time. Just remove lines 5,8,9 (`List<PrintDocument>...` `docList.add...` `docList.add...`).

Comment: Because I want to send more than one document to a virtual printer (which is my default printer). The virtual printer collects the docs and prints if i click ok. @Shirkam

Comment: I think one of us is misunderstanding something. Where do you send that `List` to your virtual printer? As far as I can see, you send data with `Print` method, which not uses the `List` at all, just the object it belongs.

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks now i see that the list was unnecessary in the way i used it

Answer (score 1):

i think this looks more cleaner, i have ommitted List docList as it doesn't requires.

```
private void PrintFile_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        List<string> docs= new List<string> 
        {
         @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\1\1.pdf",
         @"C:\Users\test\Desktop\1\2.pdf"
        };

        foreach(var doc in docs)
        {
              var printDoc = new PrintDocument();
              printDoc.DocumentName = doc;
              printDoc.Print();
        }
}
```

Comment: You can also get that list from somewhere else, and that will look definitely cleaner.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: If we saying about code refactoring, maybe better to move logic of document printing to another method, outside event handler. Realize logic directly in event handler is not a good practice. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048196/functionality-code-in-event-handler-bad-practice

Comment: All right thanks @Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

It is better to refactor this method and move out the printing logic outside the method. Probably you do not need list as well. If you have some pattern for the file names, you can further optimize it.

```
    private void PrintFile_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDoc(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\1\1.pdf");
        PrintDoc(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\1\2.pdf");
    }

    private void PrintDoc(string documentPath)
    {
        PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
        printDoc.DocumentName = documentPath;
        printDoc.Print();
    }
```